# Nuget Package Explorer - is there a way to prompt the user to enter a value for a certain field in one of the files in the package

Tags: nuget, nuget-package

I created a package that contains a web.config.transform file - that is, a partial web.config that is to be added to the existing web.config in the solution when the package is installed.  Inside this web.config.transform, I have (showing a partial piece of code):

```
<add name="**NAME**-Local" connectionString="data source=**DB SERVER**;initial catalog=**DATABASE**;user id=**USER ID**;password=**PASSWORD**;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

When a developer adds this package to their solution which adds the above line of code to the connection strings element, the parts that have the double asterisks will be different in every application.  For example, developer 1 is developing an app whose database server is called "WidgetsDb".  Okay, so "WidgetsDb" would replace DB SERVER in double asterisks.  Great, now developer 2 is developing an app that uses database server called "BicyclesDb". So, these two developers are using different database servers, as you can see.

I envision the solution to this as something like a pop up when installing the NuGet package prompting the user what their database server is named, what their database is named, what the user ID is, what the password is, etc.  All this data will be used in the above connection string where you see the double asterisks.  I hope I'm making sense.  Is this possible?  I'm aware of the different tokens you can reference in the package, such as $rootnamespace$, $id$, $version$, $author$, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this using a powershell-built form to gather the input.  This can be achieved by adding an install.ps1 file to your package, which will run whenever the package is installed.  This code sample is roughly what you would need to create the form and make it pop up during installation of the package.  $databaseName.Text will contain whatever they typed in.

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") 

    $objForm = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form 
    $objForm.Text = "Data Entry Form"
    $objForm.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(300,200) 
    $objForm.StartPosition = "CenterScreen"

    $objForm.KeyPreview = $True
    $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Enter") 
        {$x=$databaseName.Text;$objForm.Close()}})
    $objForm.Add_KeyDown({if ($_.KeyCode -eq "Escape") 
        {$objForm.Close()}})

    $OKButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $OKButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,120)
    $OKButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $OKButton.Text = "OK"
    $OKButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
    $objForm.Controls.Add($OKButton)

    $CancelButton = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
    $CancelButton.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(150,120)
    $CancelButton.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(75,23)
    $CancelButton.Text = "Cancel"
    $CancelButton.Add_Click({$objForm.Close()})
    $objForm.Controls.Add($CancelButton)

    $objLabel = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Label
    $objLabel.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,20) 
    $objLabel.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(280,20) 
    $objLabel.Text = "Please enter the database name in the space below:"
    $objForm.Controls.Add($objLabel) 

    $databaseName = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
    $databaseName.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,40) 
    $databaseName.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(260,20) 
    $objForm.Controls.Add($databaseName) 

    $objForm.Topmost = $True

    $objForm.Add_Shown({$objForm.Activate()})
    [void] $objForm.ShowDialog()
```

Extending this form to capture whatever else you need should be easy enough.